# List/Array data manipulation and optimization

Tags: python-3.x, loops, optimization, data-manipulation

Please refer the algorithm below:
I have an array called `bld` which takes `steps` as columns and `floors` as rows.

```
class testing:
    
    def abc(self, steps: int):
        
        floors = int(input('enter the number of floors: '))
        
        bld = []
        
        for i in range(steps):
            bld.append([])
            
            for j in range(floors):
                bld[i].append(j)
        print (bld)        
        
        return bld
    
def main():
    sf = testing()
    bld_array = sf.abc(20)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output is:
`[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]`

I want to add a condition at step 10 to have expected output:
`[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], **[0,0,0]**, [0,1,2], [0,1,2]`

Any leads on how to approach this is much appreciated.

Comment: They are lists of lists, not arrays.

Comment: @DYZ thanks! I edited.

Comment: FYR, your whole function can be written as `bids=[list(range(floors)) for i in range(steps)]`. No need for all those loops and appends.

Comment: You don't need to annotate types in python: and not only you don't need to do so, but you shouldn't! Python has duck-typing philosophy (I let you google it), which is against type annotations!

Comment: @BlackBeans Annotations are specifically a feature of Python, with *a lot* of work having been put into it by the Python maintainers. Python is *definitely not* against type annotations!

Comment: Well, no, annotations are not a specific feature of Python (at least not with a basic typing usage)... It is a basic feature of all statically typed languages, and in python they don't have any meaning by them self. They don't enforce anything, and are useful only in association with other tools (stricter syntax/meaning checker, Cython (not the same as CPython), documentation, ...) I let you check the pep 3107 for more informations, but basically all I say here comes from there. Anyway, annotations are not suited for beginners IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
bids = [[i for i in range(floors)] if j != 10 else [0 for i in range(floors)] for j in range(steps)]
```

And, btw, your class name should be CamelCase.

**EDIT:**
Why CamelCase.

First of all, by CamelCase I mean why I should, which means all lowercase except the beginning of a word, acronyms in capital letters (ie. HTTPServer – HTTP stands for HyperText Transfer Protocol), all words sticked together. Sometimes this is called PascalCase, and camelCase excludes the first word from being capitalized (like functions in javascript). I don't know who's right, but in python it's callede CamelCase.

Second, the reason. CamelCase (or CapCase) is officially the case to use when naming classes. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) for other naming conventions. So, you might ask, ok, that's the convention, but why should I following it? The code runs the same, right?

Well, yes, up to when you need to dive into more complex problems, and names you give to things really matter because they borrow with them meanings, way-of-doing, and relate to things you've done before. For example, once you're used to code with conventions, reading the documentation is quite like reading a tutorial, because as soon as you see a name, you already have a huge hint on what it's going to happen to the object related, how to use it, etc..

And, this, is only for your personal benefits. Just think about other people reading *your* code, and not the other way around. It's much better for them if they can put all their efforts into the meaning of your code, and not it's form (just like you can read sentences with lots of mistakes, but it's much easier to read a correct one). This enhances greatly the chances – for example – to have an answer on forums, when you present your code.

Finally, I think conventions model the way you think. If you follow them, you tend to think how you are supposed to when you are writing code in a certain language, and so to make idiomatic code (= good code).

Comment: The classname thing is just a convention, it doesn't _need_ to be CamelCase.

Comment: Conventions are a lot. Whenever someone else reads your code, they can understand it more deeply if you follow conventions. If it is camel case, we know it is a class. If it is snake case, we know it is an object, etc.. It is not important if you are the only one to ever read your own code, but this is quite important in the opposite case, and your own question proves that the former case is extremely rare. Further more, following python conventions ensures you you are coding in the idiomatic way (this is true for all programming languages, really).

Comment: Agreed. Just pointing out that it doesn't need to be that way for correctness of code. Maybe you should add why it should be CamelCase to your answer.